# Passing values from one view controller to another in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on Swift, I've got an error in tableview's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.
I want to pass a value to another view controller i.e 'secondViewController'. Here EmployeesId is an Array. The relevant code is as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var view: Dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard") as Dashboard

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    secondViewController.UserId = employeesId[indexPath.item]  //getting an error here.
}
```

But I am getting this Error:
  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what type is UserId?  If it's a UILabel, then it'll be nil until the view is rendered.  Also, where is secondViewController set?

Comment: It should be indexPath.row, not indexPath.item, but I don't know if that will fix your problem. Are you sure that employeesId[indexPath.item] is not nil?

Comment: is UserId (strong, nonatomic) in the seconfViewController?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a general solution with two assumptions. First, UserId is not a UILabel.  Second, you meant to use `view` which was instantiated in the second line, instead of using `secondViewController`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var view: Dashboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard") as Dashboard
    view.userId = employeesId[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
    
}
```

Here's what Dashboard looks like:

```
class Dashboard: UIViewController {
    var userId: String!
    @IBOutlet var userIDLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        userIDLabel.text = UserId
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: if i want to call a web service using "userid" in viewDidLoad() how i will call because user id return nil

Answer (score 4):

We can pass value using "struct" in swift 3

1. Create a swift file in your project
2. Create a class in the swift file created  like bellow

   ```
       class StructOperation {
         struct glovalVariable {
         static var userName = String();
        }
    }
   ```
3. Assing  value to  "static var userName"  variable of  " struct glovalVariable" in "StructOperation" class from First View Controller like

   ```
    @IBAction func btnSend(_ sender: Any) {
       StructOperation.glovalVariable.userName = "Enamul Haque";
      //Code Move to Sencon View Controller
    }
   ```
4. In destination view controller get value like bellow

   ```
    var username = StructOperation.glovalVariable.userName;
   ```

Comment: this is better way or passing global value as other controller?@Enamul Haque

Answer (score 0):

is `UserId(strong, nonatomic)` in the secondViewController?

If it is weak, it sent trash on the fly. You have to make it strong.