# Setting a value in one file from another programmatically [Swift]

Tags: swift, nsviewcontroller

Not the same as: [Passing values ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676687/passing-values-from-one-view-controller-to-another-in-swift) and [Swift - programmatically ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374759/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene) was not helpful for my situation.

When I press a button in one file (NSViewController)

```
@IBAction func bookPressed(sender: NSButton) { 
    var popVC = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", 
        bundle: nil)?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("PopoverViewController") as? NSViewController
    popVC.bookName = "hello"
}
```

I want this file to show the results of bookName = "hello"

```
class PopoverViewController: NSViewController {

    let bookName: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(bookName)
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you also can use singleton :)

Comment: Don't use a singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast popVC as `PopoverViewController` so you can set the `bookName` property, as `NSViewController` does not have a property `bookName`:

```
var popVC = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", 
    bundle: nil)?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("PopoverViewController") as? PopoverViewController
```

Then you will need to present the view controller you just instantiated using `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)`

Furthermore, in your `PopoverViewController` class, you should use `var` for `bookName` because it is immutable as is.

Comment: I didn't realize that I needed to use `presentViewController`, too. Thank you.